# Oracle database password/user invalid

Tags: oracle

I am trying to connect to oracle instance. I succeed in SQL developer with the same account and password, but when i try in intellij it gives me ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password.
Also please note that i succeed in connection in SQL Developer only if i choose to connect as dba for that USER. password and account is not wrong for sure..

Comment: If it doesn't let you explicitly select a role, does it maybe let you provide the username as "<user> as sysdba"?

Comment: Note that "as sysdba" usually authenticates against a different external source than normal database authentication. It is therefore possible in some cases that the "as sysdba" password will not match the normal password for the user if the external password file has not been updated to match whatever is current in the database. If you can't use the sysdba password for normal (not sysdba) authentication, then you probably don't have the right password. The sysdba role should not be used for normal login and database operations.

Comment: *i succeed in connection in SQL Developer only if i choose to connect as dba*... Looks like you try to connect as a `SYS` user, because this is the only user that **must** log in `as SYSDBA`. Generally, `SYS` user should not be used after you have set up the database and created accounts for administrative tasks, so you do not need to use this account for any database operations more than once. Please, revise your security model and create general account for your database and avoid use of `SYS`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Oracle Database JDBC Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/urls.htm#JJDBC28282) you have

> set the `internal_logon` connection property to `SYSDBA` or `SYSOPER`.

IntelliJ IDEA offers this in the "Advanced" Tab [image]

To get the properties pre-filled here, you have to select or maybe even download a driver to use. (It's offered in the "General" tab on the bottom.)